# Manage phone numbers for bots

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm testing the communication endpoint of Microsoft Graph Api, I used the incident bot example to start over, but I want to know if it's possible to connect a external call (PSTN) to my bot, when I try to use this docs: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number** it's does not work.

there is a different configuration that I have to do?

Comment: Could you 
please confirm if you have [Assign a Virtual User License](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number) (or Phone System license) to the Application Instance to bot?

Comment: Yes it was possible